# Persist list of enumeration on JPA, converter not working

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to persist a list of enumeration on the database, using JPA and hibernate.

My model looks like that:

```
@Id
@Column
String id;

@Column
@Convert(converter = EnumConverter.class)
List<Enum> listEnum;
```

And I would like to persist that list of `enum` as `String` and use a converter (`EnumConverter`) in order to store it and read it from the database.

My converter uses Jackson in order to serialize and deserialize. Example:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class EnumListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Enum>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final List<Enum> list) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Enum> convertToEntityAttribute(final String list) {
        try {
            return Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(list, Enum[].class));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that is storing it fine, but when I try to get the code, it returns me an array of size 1 (type `ArrayList`) like the following instead of an array of size 3:

```
"["Value1","Value2","Value3"]"
```

I am using a `CrudRepository` with a simple native query:

```
SELECT list from the entity;
```

Does someone know what I'm missing? I would like to have an `ArrayList` of three values instead of one with one value. When I debug the converter it does it right, so the problem has to be after converting.

Comment: Storing values as csv in one column is no good db design. learn about normalization

Comment: It is very simple exercise. I just wanted to do it fast and use object mapper to store and retrieve it from database.

Comment: Please post EnumConverter source code.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I added it!

Comment: @Jens, good point however some databases offer arrays as column types so if that's the case one could consider Vlad Mihalcea's library in order to map SQL arrays, see this:https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

I was almost giving up when I found this example from the documentation,

> Example 4:  Apply a converter to an **element collection** of basic type:
> **@ElementCollection**
> // applies to each element in the collection
> ...

So, even if you are auto applying a converter, just place that annotation below your list.

```
@ElementCollection
@Column
@Convert(converter = EnumConverter.class)
List<Enum> listEnum;
```